# Weird corruption? Showing garbage on command-line?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3

I got a few new RPI3, with (Intenso) 8GB (class 10) SDHC cards and a original RPI PSU (5V / 2.1A).

Im running into a few very weird problems, after i installed RVM + Ruby i rebooted the system. Then i removed the X windows environment:

```
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove --purge 'libx11-.*'
```

I then saw some errors (see screenshot). Is this some form of corruption? Any idea where it comes from? and more important how to prevent it?

[image]

Yesterday i also had similar issues with another card (bought 3 of these). I put it away thinking it would be a faulty card, but now im suspecting there is more going on.

---

Full image https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVVLO.png

Comment: There was no actual screenshot or evidence of one until I looked at the markup version, so I've inserted a (portion) of it above.

Comment: I think you should backup now. Run fsck from a Linux Live CD , while the SD card is inserted in a USB Card Reader.

Comment: @flakeshake, yeah but there is no data on it. Once its stable i make backups.

Comment: Running `e2fsck` is still a good idea, although Raspbian *should* do that by default at boot, you might as well double check it yourself.  If there are corruptions it may fix them explicitly.

Answer (score 3):

> sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove --purge 'libx11-.*'

A debatably useful thing to do, since the complete X11 install is probably only a few hundred MB.

Interesting to note the reference to "dependency problems, but doing as you requested anyway".  I'd say there's then a bug in apt/dpkg that shows up, but this is debatable too based the extent to which:

1) A tool should allow you to shoot you in your own foot.  Or drill a hole in your own hand, or whatever, if you misuse it.

2) Appropriate warnings were provided.

3) This is really a consequence of having done something the wrong way, or just coincidence.

It appears you are still in a GUI so I presume this is from an SSH or other remote terminal.

> Yesterday i also had similar issues

You don't explain what you mean by "similar".  If you mean more or less *the same*, then obviously the result here is predictable.  If that's all it is, I would not worry too much for now, but also *don't do the same thing over and over again expecting a different result*.

If you want a GUI-less install, start with the jessie-lite image (presuming you are using Raspbian).  My preference is to actually start with the jessie-lite image (about 1.5 GB) and then install the GUI the way I want it; including a WM and various applications this adds another 1/2 GB, which is why I am pretty sure "x11-*" doesn't add up to much, depending on what also gets removed.  I'm guessing `--auto-remove --purge` might do quite a bit and saved you somewhere around that, but before you take a wall down with a sledgehammer, make sure you understand what's in the wall.  If you aren't sure, don't use a sledgehammer.

Comment: I'm running a server, no need or extra stuff (i need the space). Anyway, its not a clear thing since the corruption seems random. Yesterday (after reboot) i tried to run "gem install <any gem>" and it throws some garbage (when calling awk). Your approach, is exactly what i did to start. Bu since that run into yesterdays problems, today i tried the NOOB route.  After i installed, i only did a  "sync", followed by "sudo reboot" :-/

Comment: But it's so satisfying to sledgehammer your way through a wall...